# VB.NET How to Minimize a window to the Taskbar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, minimize

How can i Minimize the window to the Taskbar?

im using:

```
FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

;)

Comment: How can I restore the form using a shortcut (for example Ctrl+R) so I can restore and bring the form to focus again.